# JRadio Buttons are "Hiding" in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout, jradiobutton

Please have a look at the following code

```
package normal;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Form extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel heightLabel, weightLabel, waistLabel, neckLabel, hipsLabel,genderLabel,valuesLabel,bfPercentageLabel;
    private JLabel logoLabel; 

    private ImageIcon logo;

    private JTextField heightTxt, weightTxt, waistTxt, neckTxt, hipsTxt;

    private JRadioButton maleRadio, femaleRadio, inchesRadio, cmRadio;
    private ButtonGroup genderGroup, valuesGroup;

    private JComboBox percentageCombo;

    private JPanel centerPanel, northPanel, southPanel;


    public Form()
    {
        //Declaring instance variables  
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height: ");
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight: ");
        waistLabel = new JLabel("Waist: ");
        neckLabel = new JLabel("Neck: ");
        hipsLabel = new JLabel("Hips: ");
        genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender: ");
        valuesLabel = new JLabel("Values in: ");


        logoLabel = new JLabel();
        logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/calc_logo_final_2_edit.gif"));
        logoLabel.setIcon(logo);



        heightTxt = new JTextField(10);
        weightTxt = new JTextField(10);
        waistTxt = new JTextField(10);
        neckTxt = new JTextField(10);
        hipsTxt = new JTextField(10);

        maleRadio = new JRadioButton("Male");
        femaleRadio = new JRadioButton("Female");
        genderGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        genderGroup.add(maleRadio);
        genderGroup.add(femaleRadio);

        inchesRadio = new JRadioButton("Inches");
        cmRadio = new JRadioButton("Centimeters");
        valuesGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        valuesGroup.add(inchesRadio);
        valuesGroup.add(cmRadio);

        percentageCombo = new JComboBox();
        percentageCombo.addItem("No Value is Set");

        this.add(createNorthPanel(),"North");
        this.add(createCenterPanel(),"Center");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    private JPanel createNorthPanel()
    {
        northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        northPanel.add(logoLabel);

        return northPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createCenterPanel()
    {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        centerPanel.setLayout(gbl);

        //creating a jpanel for gender radio buttons
        JPanel genderPanel = new JPanel();
        genderPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        genderPanel.add(genderLabel);
        genderPanel.add(maleRadio);
        genderPanel.add(femaleRadio);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(heightLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(heightTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(weightLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(weightTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(waistLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(waistTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(neckLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(neckTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(hipsLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(hipsTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(genderLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(maleRadio,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,-10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(femaleRadio,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(50,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(valuesLabel,gbc);



        return centerPanel;


    }
}
```

As you can see, the JRadio button "female" is hiding a part of it, and once you move your cursor, it shows up completely. I guess this is happening because it is using minus spacing in "insets".

However I did it like that to reduce the gap between 2 radio buttons. Male is in `gridx = 2`, and female is in `gridx = 3`, which is a massive space between the buttons.So I used minus space in insets to reduce the space, unfortunately it came like this.

I tried adding the JLabel, maleRadio and femaleRadio into a seperate JPanel which is having `flowlayout`, and put it into `gbc.gridx = 2; gbc.gridy = 3;`. It made everything worst by matching all the cells in `gridy = 3` into the width of new JPanel.

Please help me to reduce the gap between these 2 JRadio buttons, without having any issue. Thank you.

Comment: `Please have a look at the following code`-- Your code is too long and unwieldy to look at a glance, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `As you can see, the JRadio button`-- we cannot see anything , post a screenshot for the problem you are having.

Comment: @Sepala : What's the point of using the same GridBagConstraints's object, if you have to write the whole code again, try to skip values that you already had set, use only those that you need to apply anew

Answer (score 4):

- Dont extend `JFrame` rather create an instance and use that.
- Also I see you add your radio buttons to a panel but you dont add the panel rather you re-add the radio buttons to `centerpanel`? choose one way lose the other (though I think this might have occurred in trying to mend the problem?)
- An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) most importantly is compilable (via correct syntax and no compile error) and runnable (via **a main method** and *no runtime exceptions* (unless thats the problem :P) - like your reading of the image - please find a way to include resources i.e link to an URL with the logo or make a method return a simple image the same size as logo or simply leave it out).

The problem is here:

```
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(15, -10, 0, 0);
    centerPanel.add(femaleRadio, gbc);
```

-10 should definitely not be there (maybe typo?) as this will cause it to overlap or in this case *underlap* another component, rather use anything greater than or equal to 0:

```
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(15, 10, 0, 0);
    centerPanel.add(femaleRadio, gbc);
```

which would give us:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also it is important to note `GridBagContsraints` like `gridx` etc start at 0 and not 1.

+1 to @Gagandeeps balis comment on re-using values which have been set already and are the same in `GridBagConstraints`, here is your code with all talked about fixes:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Form {

    private JLabel heightLabel, weightLabel, waistLabel, neckLabel, hipsLabel, genderLabel, valuesLabel, bfPercentageLabel;
    private JLabel logoLabel;
    private ImageIcon logo;
    private JTextField heightTxt, weightTxt, waistTxt, neckTxt, hipsTxt;
    private JRadioButton maleRadio, femaleRadio, inchesRadio, cmRadio;
    private ButtonGroup genderGroup, valuesGroup;
    private JComboBox percentageCombo;
    private JPanel centerPanel, northPanel, southPanel;

    public Form() {
        //Declaring instance variables  
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height: ");
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight: ");
        waistLabel = new JLabel("Waist: ");
        neckLabel = new JLabel("Neck: ");
        hipsLabel = new JLabel("Hips: ");
        genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender: ");
        valuesLabel = new JLabel("Values in: ");

        logoLabel = new JLabel();
        //logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/calc_logo_final_2_edit.gif"));
        //logoLabel.setIcon(logo);

        heightTxt = new JTextField(10);
        weightTxt = new JTextField(10);
        waistTxt = new JTextField(10);
        neckTxt = new JTextField(10);
        hipsTxt = new JTextField(10);

        maleRadio = new JRadioButton("Male");
        femaleRadio = new JRadioButton("Female");
        genderGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        genderGroup.add(maleRadio);
        genderGroup.add(femaleRadio);

        inchesRadio = new JRadioButton("Inches");
        cmRadio = new JRadioButton("Centimeters");
        valuesGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        valuesGroup.add(inchesRadio);
        valuesGroup.add(cmRadio);

        percentageCombo = new JComboBox();
        percentageCombo.addItem("No Value is Set");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createNorthPanel(), "North");
        frame.add(createCenterPanel(), "Center");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    private JPanel createNorthPanel() {
        northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        northPanel.add(logoLabel);

        return northPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createCenterPanel() {
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        centerPanel.setLayout(gbl);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15, 5, 0, 0);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        centerPanel.add(heightLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        centerPanel.add(heightTxt, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        centerPanel.add(weightLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        centerPanel.add(weightTxt, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        centerPanel.add(waistLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        centerPanel.add(waistTxt, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        centerPanel.add(neckLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        centerPanel.add(neckTxt, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        centerPanel.add(hipsLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        centerPanel.add(hipsTxt, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        centerPanel.add(genderLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        centerPanel.add(maleRadio, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        centerPanel.add(femaleRadio, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(50, 5, 0, 0);
        centerPanel.add(valuesLabel, gbc);

        return centerPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Form();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hehe stumbled upon the problem as broswing the code, at first I was stumped though :P

Comment: I just got this thingy on my side too, just now, thought of positing this as a comment, but found you had already answered :-)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Thanks for the reply David. But this is the case I am talking about. See, the gap between male and female radio buttons are too much. I used minus values because of that, to reduce the gap.

Comment: @Sepala tried just setting them all to 0? Im talking about the label and 2 radio buttos in question? thats the best smallest the gap will get without using negative an overlapping components using current `LayoutManager` (not that Im a GridBag guru :)).  Maybe try nesting `LayoutManager`s to achieve your desired look. Also take a look at my update.

Comment: @Sepala : Try this [**JRadioButton.setMargin()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)), hopefully this might be able to help.